# Add fields to Ubercart cart form

Tags: 7, forms, ubercart

I would like to add one extra field to existing default cart table form.

I need to output a field behind the product title (it is a field containing info about product type)

The field is part of the product content type. Idea behind this is: Ubercart shows by default only the title of product in cart form; i have created subtitle field in product content type, which describes the article in detail, as sometimes product titles are the same.

I have suggestion to use hook_form_alter but cannot find any examples how i can implement this hook in custom module to achieve this.

I am on Drupal 7 - 7.x-3.1 Ubercart.

Thanks for any clues !

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602347/add-custom-fields-to-shopping-cart-display-ubercart-3) thread on SO.

Comment: Thanks, friend. I will see into it. This may be worth an answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome - glad if I helped :) to further understand what is going on there, check out Ubercart's [tables API](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/tapir) as that is what is used for building the checkout tables.

Comment: Tnx. I want to hack in cart tables btw, not the checkout pane...

Comment: All Ubercart tables are using TAPIr, so you will need it anyway.